# Steps to create escrow payment integration in android source code

Tags: android, paypal, escrow

I want to integrate Escrow Payment Integration in our e-commerce android application. Please tell me the all steps to successfully create Escrow Account integration in android application.

Comment: Did you find any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate paytym like this..

```
   Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
  //for testing environment
  Service = PaytmPGService.getStagingService();
  PaytmMerchant Merchant = new PaytmMerchant("https://pguat.paytm.com/merchant-chksum/ChecksumGenerator","https://pguat.paytm.com/merchant-chksum/ValidateChksum");

  Log.e("value","value");

  Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

  //these are mandatory parameters
  paramMap.put("REQUEST_TYPE", "DEFAULT");
  paramMap.put("ORDER_ID", String.valueOf(randomInt));
  //MID provided by paytm
  paramMap.put("MID", "id provided by paytm");
  paramMap.put("CUST_ID", "CUST123");
  paramMap.put("CHANNEL_ID", "WAP");
  paramMap.put("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "Retail");
  paramMap.put("WEBSITE", "paytm");
  paramMap.put("TXN_AMOUNT", "1");
  paramMap.put("THEME", "merchant");

  PaytmOrder Order = new PaytmOrder(paramMap);


  Service.initialize(Order, Merchant,null);
  Log.e("value1111","value");
  Service.startPaymentTransaction(this, true, true, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onTransactionSuccess(Bundle bundle) {
          app.getLogger().error("Transaction Success :" + bundle);
          Log.e("Transaction Success :",""+bundle);
      }

      @Override
      public void onTransactionFailure(String s, Bundle bundle) {
        app.getLogger().error("Transaction Failure :" + s + "\n" + bundle);
          Log.e("Transaction Failure :",s+"    "+bundle);
      }

      @Override
      public void networkNotAvailable() {
        app.getLogger().error("network unavailable :");
          Log.e("network unavailable :","network unavailable :    ");
      }

      @Override
      public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String s) {
         app.getLogger().error("clientAuthenticationFailed :" + s);
          Log.e("clientAuthenticationFailed :",s+"    ");
      }

      @Override
      public void someUIErrorOccurred(String s) {
         app.getLogger().error("someUIErrorOccurred :" + s);
          Log.e("someUIErrorOccurred :",s+"    ");
      }

      @Override
      public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int i, String s, String s2) {
         app.getLogger().error("errorLoadingWebPage :" + i + "\n" + s + "\n" + s2);
          Log.e("errorLoadingWebPage :",i+"    "+s+"   "+s2);
      }
  });
}
```

`ChecksumGenerator` and `ValidateChksum` are provide by paytym team.

Comment: Thanks sir to give me answer but i am not unable to understand that this is paytm transaction but i want to know about escrow account . and 1000 is the by default price which we can set . And please tell me that this can be work for U.S.A. price .